# Rails starting failure on OSX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I am using ruby 2.0.0, rails 3.2.13. When I try to run a rails app : here's the message I get  when I run `rails server RAILS_ENV=production`

```
/Users/myhome/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require': cannot load such file -- rb-fsevent (LoadError)
    from /Users/myhome/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/myhome/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /Users/myhome/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
    from /Users/myhome/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from /Users/myhome/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from /Users/myhome/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /Users/git/gitlab/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /Users/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /Users/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Someone could help ?

Comment: Are you using Guard that's not in a :development group in your gemfile?

Comment: cannot load such file -- rb-fsevent (LoadError) Do a bundle install. maybe that will fix it.

Comment: gem 'rb-fsevent', :require => false does this solve it?

Comment: Try to install the missing gem: `gem install rb-fsevent`

Comment: @KeesSonnema that was it !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

move your gem 'rb-fsevent' in your development group and `bundle install`

```
group :development, :test do
     gem 'rb-fsevent'
end
```